# common and unique elements in different vectors

Tags: r

I have two string vectors  and I want to return what they have common and what is unique for vector a and for vector b.

```
a<- letters[seq( from = 1, to = 10 )]
b<- letters[seq( from = 6, to = 15 )]

common =  "f" "g" "h" "i" "j"
unique_a = "a" "b" "c" "d" "e" 
unique_b = "k" "l" "m" "n" "o"
```

Comment: `intersect(a, b); setdiff(a, b); setdiff(b, a)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Common elements:

```
a[a %in% b] # or b[b %in% a]
[1] "f" "g" "h" "i" "j"
```

Unique to a:

```
a[!a %in% b] # or a[b %in% a]
[1] "a" "b" "c" "d" "e"
```

Unique to b:

```
b[!b %in% a] # or b[a %in% b]
[1] "k" "l" "m" "n" "o"
```

> **Notes**

It is worth pointing out that `intersect` and `setdiff` will discard any duplicated values in the arguments. Whereas `%in%` will keep duplicates. So if we had duplicated values we will get different results. For example, indroducing a duplicated element **a** in vector a:

```
a <- c(a, "a")
[1] "a" "b" "c" "d" "e" "f" "g" "h" "i" "j" "a"
# Duplicated element a is discarded
setdiff(a, b)
[1] "a" "b" "c" "d" "e"
# Keeps duplicated element a
a[!a %in% b]
[1] "a" "b" "c" "d" "e" "a"
```

Answer (score 4):

As was already mentioned in the comments by @David Arenburg, you can use the commands `intersect` and `setdiff` in `base`-R:

```
> a<- letters[seq( from = 1, to = 10 )]
> b<- letters[seq( from = 6, to = 15 )]
> a
 [1] "a" "b" "c" "d" "e" "f" "g" "h" "i" "j"
> b
 [1] "f" "g" "h" "i" "j" "k" "l" "m" "n" "o"
> intersect(a, b)
[1] "f" "g" "h" "i" "j"
> setdiff(a, b)
[1] "a" "b" "c" "d" "e"
> setdiff(b, a)
[1] "k" "l" "m" "n" "o"
```

Comment: Nice copy paste there

Comment: Well comments are not meant for answers. Why do leave the question unanswered? It might deter people who need an answer from looking into the question at all.

Comment: Yes, but shame-sly copy/pasting without any reference is just rude.

Comment: It's not like I wouldn't have known the answer myself. I just don't see the point why so many people answer questions in comments and leave so many questions "unanswered". I'm regularly sifting through unanswered questions to see which I can answer and I don't see why I shouldn't post an answer even when someone already posted it as a comment.

Comment: Because it's called Plagiarism. See here http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251597/question-with-no-answers-but-issue-solved-in-the-comments

Comment: I didn't know about community wiki until know, thank you.